# subscription.on('open') equivalent in flutter parse-platform

Tags: flutter, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to load objects through a stream in flutter. Currently, I cannot find ways on how to implement this without calling another get function before listening.

I'm calling a `getAllObject()` function first before constructing a StreamSubscription. This is because currently in my code my stream `listenToUpdates()` relies on the `List<Objects>` that the `getAllObject()` returns.

Is there any way on how to implement this using only the stream. Or can you please give me ideas on how to tackle this scenario? Thanks in advance

### Edit

This is the function I'm calling upon loading the view.

```
Future listenToUserAddresses() async {
    setBusy(true);

    var resultingData = await _parseService.getMyAddresses(currentCustomerObject, currentUser.userId);
    _userAddresses = resultingData[0] is bool ? _userAddresses = [] : resultingData[0];
    notifyListeners();
    setBusy(false);
    
    subscription = _parseService
    .listenToUserAddressesRealTime(resultingData[1], _userAddresses)
    .listen((userAddressesData) {
      List<UserAddress> updatedUserAddresses = userAddressesData;
      if (updatedUserAddresses != null) {
        print('NOT NULL');
        _userAddresses = updatedUserAddresses;
        setBusy(false);
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        print('NULL');
        _userAddresses.clear();
        setBusy(false);
        notifyListeners();
      }
    });
  }
```

Now, this one is for the `getMyAddresses` method. This function takes in a `ParseObject` of a `Customer Class` and the current user Id which will return an array composed List of objects and a subscription.

```
Future getMyAddresses(ParseObject customerObject, String currentUserId) async {
    List result = [];
    final LiveQuery liveQuery = LiveQuery();
    QueryBuilder<ParseObject> query = QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject(_addressesCollection))
      ..whereRelatedTo('addresses', _customerCollection, customerObject.objectId)
      ..whereEqualTo('isDeleted', false);

    QueryBuilder<ParseObject> querySubscription = QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject(_addressesCollection))
      ..whereEqualTo('isDeleted', false)
      ..whereEqualTo('userId', currentUserId);

    ParseResponse response = await query.query();
    Subscription subscription = await liveQuery.client.subscribe(querySubscription);
    if(response.success && response.count != 0) {
      List<UserAddress> addresses = (jsonDecode(response.results.toString()) as List)
        .map((address) => UserAddress.fromMap(address)).toList();

      result.add(addresses);
      result.add(subscription);
      return result;
    } else {
      result.add(false);
      result.add(subscription);
      return result;
    }
  }
```

#### Disclaimer

I am using two queries: one to query a relation and the other one is for the subscription as `LiveQueries` which derived from `relations` are currently not supported. That's why I used two.

This one now is for the `stream` which is responsible for the `subscriptions.on` event.

```
Stream listenToUserAddressesRealTime(Subscription subscription, List<UserAddress> userAddress) {
    subscription.on(LiveQueryEvent.create, (value) {
        print('*** CREATE ***: ${DateTime.now().toString()}\n $value ');

        String rawJson = (value as ParseObject).toString();
        UserAddress createdObject = UserAddress.fromMap(jsonDecode(rawJson));
        userAddress.add(createdObject);
        _addressController.add(userAddress);
    });
    subscription.on(LiveQueryEvent.leave, (value) {
        print('*** LEAVE ***: ${DateTime.now().toString()}\n $value ');

        String rawJson = (value as ParseObject).toString();
        UserAddress createdObject = UserAddress.fromMap(jsonDecode(rawJson));
        userAddress.removeWhere((element) => createdObject.objectId == element.objectId);
        _addressController.add(userAddress);
    });
    subscription.on(LiveQueryEvent.delete, (value) {
        print('*** DELETE ***: ${DateTime.now().toString()}\n $value ');

        String rawJson = (value as ParseObject).toString();
        UserAddress createdObject = UserAddress.fromMap(jsonDecode(rawJson));
        userAddress.removeWhere((element) => createdObject.objectId == element.objectId);
        _addressController.add(userAddress);
    });
    subscription.on(LiveQueryEvent.enter, (value) {
        print('*** ENTER ***: ${DateTime.now().toString()}\n $value ');

        String rawJson = (value as ParseObject).toString();
        UserAddress createdObject = UserAddress.fromMap(jsonDecode(rawJson));
        userAddress.add(createdObject);
        _addressController.add(userAddress);
    });
    subscription.on(LiveQueryEvent.update, (value) {
        print('*** UPDATE ***: ${DateTime.now().toString()}\n $value ');

        String rawJson = (value as ParseObject).toString();
        UserAddress createdObject = UserAddress.fromMap(jsonDecode(rawJson));

        var index = userAddress.indexWhere((element) => element.objectId == createdObject.objectId);
        userAddress[index] = createdObject;
        _addressController.add(userAddress);
    });
    
    return _addressController.stream;
  }
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to combine my `getMyAddresses()` and `listenToUserAddressesRealTime()` into 1 method. That's why I'm looking for some ways on how to do it.

This is relatively simple in `javascript` because of the `subscriptions.on('open')`.

But in flutter I cannot find any other way. My experience in Flutter is not really there yet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you please add code for better understanding

Comment: Hi @M123 I've updated my question. Please check it. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the open event is still not available at Flutter SDK but it would be a great addition. I'd suggest you to open an issue at GitHub repo and try to help on that.

Comment: Oh! I see. I hope to see this in future updates. This feature will greatly attract developers who use firebase as their backend. I love parse as it gives you full control on your backend, unlike firebase. In the meantime, I will just stick to my current approach. Thanks!